# How can I process data in Google storage via apache airflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a CSV file in google cloud storage. I'm using google cloud composer to run apache airflow. I would like to run some bash scripts on my CSV file and store it back to google cloud storage? I tried out searching various operators, but couldn't find any operator that process files in google storage. Is there some way to get this done?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
bash_operator.BashOperator(
    task_id="process_csv",
    bash_command="gsutil cp gs://your_bucket/your_file.csv your_file.csv && "
                 "process_file your_file.csv > processed_file.csv && "
                 "gsutil cp processed_file.csv gs://your_bucket/processed_file.csv",
    execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=1),
    dag=dag
)
```

You can find more examples in this repository https://github.com/blockchain-etl/bitcoin-etl-airflow/blob/develop/dags/bitcoinetl/build_export_dag.py.

You can also use PythonOperator instead of BashOperator. Some examples can be found here https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl-airflow/blob/master/dags/export_dag.py